# How to identify the type of socket data?

Tags: java, sockets

May be i am not able to express my doubt properly in this question but still i will try. Basically i created a simple socket based chat program and everything works fine. But i think i have made many patches in it from the design point of view.

I have used ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStreams in my program. The question i want to ask is how do i identify the different type of data that i send across the network? say if it is simple String type object i directly add to `List<String> chatMessages`. Now if want to ban certain users i created an another class :-

```
public class User{
    private String name;
    private String id;
    //getters and setters
}
```

This User class means no importance to me till now but i only created it to properly identify the *action*. Thus if i receive an `instanceOf` User i can be sure that some user is to be banned. That way i dont have to hardcode strings. I mean first i thought of sending something like `"Banned User :" + userName` and then i used to check if string startsWith "Banned User :" then i take some action :p. I've created a User class but it means no importance to me in my program.

I want to know whether directly sending strings is good way or create a class for every action that is good. If i am not clear please let me know. If i have hundreds of action do i have to create hundreds of classes so i can check via instanceOf? Say now if i plan to create a BUZZ like facility that is available in yahoo messenger. Should i again create an another class named BUZZ? so it can be identified easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not send `Action` objects across the wire ? You can then subclass these `Action` objects into (say):

1. `BanUserAction`
2. `RecordChat`
3. `AddUser`

etc. and each object instance contains the data required e.g. `BanUser` contains the name of the user to be banned.

You wouldn't need to use `instanceof` since each object would implement a common `.act()` method. You can then call that method, and you *won't have to care* which object has been passed to you, since the object itself will take care of what to do (this is a core tenet of OO programming - **tell objects to do things for you**).

Note that the `act()` method may require some context passed into it e.g. a reference to the containing chat service.